# jQuery Nav Sliding Underline Modify

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a simple navbar that has an up arrow underneath it, that slides when one of the nav titles is clicked on. The arrow starts inbetween two nav titles. When a nav title is clicked on, a bit of text slides in aswell.

I want it so that when a nav title is clicked on again, the arrow underneath slides back to its starting position (which is a css class called `uparrow`). I am not sure how to do this

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7gaqnx87/)

Here is the html:

```
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="titles">
            <h3>
                <a class="webdesign">Web Design</a>
                <a class="appdesign">Application Development</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <img class="uparrow" src="img/uparrow.png">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <h4>Web Design </h4>
        <p>Blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom2">
        <h4>Application Development</h4>
        <p>Blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css for the arrows:

```
.uparrow {
    width:20px;
}

.uparrowleft {
     margin-right:180px;
     transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.uparrowright {
    margin-left:315px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

And here is the jQuery for the arrow sliding:

```
$('.webdesign').click(function() {
    $('.bottom2').hide(500);
    $('.bottom').toggle(500);
    $('.uparrow').removeClass('uparrowright');
    $('.uparrow').addClass('uparrowleft');
});

$('.appdesign').click(function() {
    $('.bottom').hide(500);
    $('.bottom2').toggle(500);
    $('.uparrow').removeClass('uparrowleft');
    $('.uparrow').addClass('uparrowright');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek6ktsLg/

The change is toggleClass on the `uparrowleft` and `uparrowright`

```
$('.webdesign').click(function() {
    $('.bottom2').hide(500);
    $('.bottom').toggle(500);
    $('.uparrow').removeClass('uparrowright');
    $('.uparrow').toggleClass('uparrowleft');
});

$('.appdesign').click(function() {
    $('.bottom').hide(500);
    $('.bottom2').toggle(500);
    $('.uparrow').removeClass('uparrowleft');
    $('.uparrow').toggleClass('uparrowright')
});
```